# Start with a tooltip displayed and area highlighted?

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, tooltip, imagemap

Great plugin with awesome documentation.

I want to know if there is a way to have the map load with an area already highlighted, and a tool-tip for that area already displayed.

Here's my fiddle:

[See My Fiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/viralshah/sb9j7/973/)

If it could start with the key `northwest` highlighted (not selected) and a tooltip that would be great.

has been messing with it for a bit but can't figure this out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in this ImageMapster demo when I add this:

[SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/juvyh/685/)

```
    $(function(){

         $('area[state="OR"]').mapster('set',true);

    });
```

For your Fiddle I could also do it. Like this

> .mapster('set', true, 'northwest');

[Your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb9j7/1034/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the .ready() function in to fire events as soon as the page finishes loading.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Inside this you can call the function which is called when your `mouseover` event is triggered. You can just specify the northwest item to be selected.